# Calling function in coffee script returns "function is not defined"

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm trying to call a function "remove_category" from the code below, but it returns 'Uncaught ReferenceError: remove_category is not defined'

```
$('.category-checkbox').on 'click', ->
    category_id = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).toggleClass 'selected'
    if $(this).hasClass('selected')
        save_category category_id
    else
        remove_category category_id
    return
```

> remove_category

```
window.remove_category = (remove_category) ->
        alert 'called'
        sessionStorage.removeItem 'categories', remove_category
        stored_categories = jQuery.grep(stored_categories, (value) ->
            value != remove_category
        )
        console.log stored_categories
        sessionStorage.setItem 'categories', JSON.stringify(stored_categories)
        return
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: And `window.remove_category = ...` is surely executed *before* the onclick handler executes...?! It's not a great idea to explicitly create global functions/properties/variables BTW...

Comment: I wasn't really sure what "window" does. Is there any other way to solve this?

Comment: Simply create the function in the same scope as the onclick handler...!? `remove_category = ...; $(..).on 'click', -> ...;`

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. It was simply, my indentation was not right. The corrected code is here.

```
$('.category-checkbox').on 'click', ->
    category_id = $(this).attr('id')
    $(this).toggleClass 'selected'
    if $(this).hasClass('selected')
        save_category category_id
    else
        remove_category category_id
    return

remove_category = (remove_category) ->
    sessionStorage.removeItem 'categories', remove_category
    stored_categories = jQuery.grep(stored_categories, (value) ->
        value != remove_category
    )
    console.log stored_categories
    sessionStorage.setItem 'categories', JSON.stringify(stored_categories)
    return
```

I forgot to put the head of remove_category to same position as $('.category-checkbo').on.....